# Most optimized way to search from all fields in person table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2019

I have a person table with following text fields and one date field and one bit field.

-PersonID
-TextPersonID
-FirstName
-MiddleName
-LastName
-Suffix
-PreferredName
-FullName
-BirthDate
-PersonVIP

There is another address table as well which contains county, city, state, country fields.

What could be most optimized way to write a stored procedure which can search among any of field using like operator. For example -

```
*usp_PersonSearch_sel @LastName='oh' should return all persons whose last name contains letters oh

*usp_PersonSearch_sel @FirstName='oh' should return all persons whose first name contains letters oh

*usp_PersonSearch_sel @FirstName='oh',@PreferredName='wi' should return all persons whose first name contains letters oh and PreferredName contains wi
```

It could be any combination of the given above columns.

Indexing is not helping because there must be leading as well as trailing %.
Full text also did not help as that is optimized for entire word searching.

Comment: [An Updated Kitchen Sink Example](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example)

Comment: For leading wild cards, there's little more you can do that ensure you have an index that just contains the columns you are going to return (assuming a single `WHERE` on the column with the wildcard). Then, at least, the data engine can scan the smallest amount of data. If you are including other columns in the `WHERE`, then ensuring a relevant index for those columns, while having the rest in the `INCLUDE` will help.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I should have mentioned that we are dealing with at least ten million records. About relevant index - I am not sure if it's clever idea to create as many indexes as columns. Please note that I can receive search queries on any column. Also, having so many columns will slow down inserts badly.

Comment: *If* the index doesn't include all the columns that the data engine needs to complete the query then for a query with only leading wild cards it will almost certainly scan the clustered index/heap, as it will have no idea how many key lookups it going to need to do if it scans a smaller index.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Thanks for sharing. I followed the same pattern but when I call my SP from multiple threads, performance is not good enough. Thats why I am looking to see if there is any better way to search or I need to look for solutions outside sql server.

Comment: 10 million rows is nothing, really, but you're not going to be able to solve this problem with indexes if searches need leading wildcards against any column. If you want help, [please see this](https://erikdarlingdata.com/how-to-get-answers-to-sql-server-performance-questions/) - we need specifics, like execution plan details, waits, etc. - if you want any help resolving performance issues, we need to know why it's slow and what your threshold is for "slow" and how big the table is and how much memory you have etc.

Comment: If end users are able to perform any kind of search they want across any number of columns, this seems to be something you should consider optimizing at the application layer - e.g. using Elasticsearch, Solr, Algolia, or other similar products that are designed specifically to support searching without having to communicate directly with the database. These are especially effective when searches happen much more frequently than updates.

Comment: "...It could be any combination of the given above columns..." -- If that's the case consider using Full Text Search with trigrams.

Comment: Someone mentioned elasticsearch and i agree, it's pretty good for this kind of work. even if you're not searching wildcards, it will be hard to match the same performance in sql server if you're dealing with so many rows. It's probably hard even if you manage to swallow the whole register in memory and match strings by regex or friends

Comment: @AaronBertrand Thanks a lot for your suggestions and inputs! I am also considering elastic search but just wanted to make sure that I am not missing any trick in sleeve. Your article was super helpful!